# Hide <div> with selected index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm fixing the piece of the jQuery code on the page. The basic idea of the page is to list the users and show user's delegate (in `<div id="show_hidden_delegate">` if value of the user's `<select id="delegate_form">` is set to 1. HTML code is generated by our application so I can't tell how many users will occur on the page. But mentioned `<select>` is always followed by manipulated `<div>`.

So I'm trying to find value of the select with id `delegate_form`, checking it in `.each()` loop and showing/hiding div. Bellow is the partially working code.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('*[id*=delegate_form]').each(function(index){
      if($(this).val() == '1'){
        $("#show_hidden_delegate").show();
        alert("Index = " + index);
      } else {
        $("#show_hidden_delegate").hide();
       alert("Index = " + index);               
      }
  });
});
```

In my test input, value of the first select is 1, second is 2 (there can't be any different values). But after the execution first `div` will disappear. When I tried to
use `$("#show_hidden_delegate").eq(index).hide()` nothing happened. Where do I make mistake?

FYI: First alert shows "Index = 0", second "Index = 1"

Comment: Please make a working http://jsfiddle.net of you problem.

Comment: Well, I'll try to make something, but I can't show the original code, company's secrect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, simply:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('*[id*=delegate_form]').each(function(index){
      if($(this).val() == '1'){
        $(this).next().show();
      } else {
        $(this).next().hide();              
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: well, this doesn't work. It hides element in correct order, but not the correct element. Since the hierarchy of the page is 
User
 - Delegate
User
 - Delegate
When using your code, second user is hidden and delaget is shown.

Comment: I see many problems in your request since fragment of html seems to be wrong and what you say in comments it's different. Without an abstract structure of your page it's impossible to help. Do you have many select with same id? Do you want to hide only User or also Delegate? Each delegateUser has just a value (0 or 1) or each option refers to a single user?

Comment: Problem is that I can only edit XML file which is transformed to HTML by our app. So there's quit a lot of stuff which I can see in XML but is never generated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've managed to find the workaround. Problem is, that I'm able to edit only an XML file from which is the HTML generated. And lots of things I see in XML won't be displayed on page. This is independent from script, it depends on other stuff in XML file.

But here is the workaround.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*[id*=delegate_flag]').each(function(index){
        if($(this).val() == '1'){
        $('*[id*=show_hidden_delegate').eq(index).show();
        //alert("Index = " + index);
    } else {
        $('*[id*=show_hidden_delegate').eq(index).hide();
        //alert("Index = " + index);                
    }
});
$('*[id*=delegate_form]').each(function(index){
    $(this).change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '1'){
            $('*[id*=show_hidden_delegate').eq(index).show();
            //alert("Index = " + index);
        } else {
            $('*[id*=show_hidden_delegate').eq(index).hide();
            //alert("Index = " + index);                
        }
    });
});
});
```

Only when I've used regex to find div to hide, I was able to show/hide it properly. I have to check it twice because one page contains combo to select value `id="delegate_form"` and other pages contain hidden value `id="delegate_flage"` and no combo.