# Need to use a Function on Multiple Div Box onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is only for IE.
I have a function noted below it copies the content of the div when the div is clicked. It works fine. It used the getElementById.
I have 19 items I would like to use this for ... 'option1 - option19.
Instead of having to create 19 variables is there any other way of doing this...
I am totally a noob to this stuff....

```
function CopyToClip() {
    var Cdiv = document.getElementById('option1');
    Cdiv.contentEditable = 'true';
    var controlRange;
    if (document.body.createControlRange) {
        controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
        controlRange.addElement(Cdiv);
        controlRange.execCommand('Copy');
    }
    div.contentEditable = 'false';
}
```

I should mention that these id's are for Divs. 
These divs are a show / hide based on a drop down selection.
The drop down has its on function to show the selected div.
The function is:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.block').hide();
        $('#option1').show();
        $('#selectField').change(function () {
            $('.block').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

My HTML is:

```
<div class="col_1">
    <h1>communication:</h1>
    <div class="box">
  <select id="selectField" style="padding-left: 20px;width:175px">
 <option value="option1">Device Shipped to ASC</option>
 <option value="option2">Device Received at ASC</option> 
 <option value="option3">ASC Shipped Device to Store</option> 
 <option value="option4">Device Pick-up Follow-up</option>
 <option value="option5">Device Pick-up Final Reminder</option>
 <option value="option6">Impress Phase Direct Feedback</option>
 <option value="option7">Abandon Notice</option>
 <option value="option8">Mailer Shipped to Client</option>
 <option value="option9">Mailer Received by Client</option>
 <option value="option10">Mailer Pick-up Notice</option>
 <option value="option11">Mailer Final Pick-up Notice</option>
 <option value="option12">Mailer Failed to Pick-up</option>
 <option value="option13">Mailer Return Defective Device Notice</option>
 <option value="option14">Mailer Final Return Defective Device Notice</option>
 <option value="option15">Mailer Failed to Return Defective Device</option>
 <option value="option16">Mailer Defective Device Received at ASC</option>
 <option value="option17">Mailer Charges to Customer</option>
 <option value="option18">Mailer Process Confirmation</option>
 <option value="option19">Quote Un-replied</option>
 </select>

<div id="option2" class="block" style="background-color:white" onClick="javascript:CopyToClip()"> blah </div>
```

Had I have 19 of this divs.
I don't know if this helps ... Sorry I am in way over my head on this one.

Comment: Note: *document ready* event handlers do not belong inside a *window load* handler (which happens later).

Comment: Can you provide sample HTML too to allow a complete answer?

Comment: Can't you just enumerate the elements by walking the DOM tree and attach the function to their `onclick` properties in sequence? A simple `for` is probably all you need.

Comment: @IvyLynx: In jQuery you would never iterate to connect event handlers!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie So? How does jQuery attach those handlers internally anyway?

Comment: @IvyLynx: Of course, but given this is a `jQuery` question you want to keep the code simple and short (which is what jQuery is all about), otherwise you might as well do it in machine code and say *at least this is fast* :)

Comment: @user3837156: Without suitable sample HTML, or a clearer explanation of the options that the dropdown selects this question will not get much attention I'm afraid. Best add some sample HTML soon (a JSFiddle would be best).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie lol fair enough, I'm not much of a jQuery guy :P

Comment: @IvyLynx it automatically loops the `this` property which stores your elements. say you do $('.class'); internally it does `for(i=0;i<target.length;i++){this[i]=target[i];} this.length = target.length;` just a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to hack things about a little, and your clipboard code will not work on all browsers:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/THU5f/2/

```
function CopyToClip($div) {
    var div = $div[0];
    div.contentEditable = 'true';
    var controlRange;
    if (document.body.createControlRange) {
        controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
        controlRange.addElement(div);
        controlRange.execCommand('Copy');
        alert("Copied: " + div.html());
    }
    div.contentEditable = 'false';
}

$(function () {
    // Hide copy button
    $('#copy').hide();
    // Hide all content divs
    $('.content').hide();

    $('#selectField').change(function () {
        // Show the copy button
        $('#copy').show();
        // Hide all content divs
        $(".content").fadeOut();
        // Show the select content div
        $('#' + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
    });
    $('#copy').click(function(){
        // Get the div the current selection points to
        var $div = $('#' + $('#selectField').val());
        // Copy the div to the clipboard
        CopyToClip($div);
    });

});
```

*I added comments throughout. Hope this helps.*

Comment: You are awesome!!!! This works perfect.. I have last ask... is there anyway to by default have option1 loaded??

Comment: Figured it out... just added the line:      $('#' + $('#selectField').val()).show();  Thanks for all of your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on similar thing lately. I was supposed to show/hide DIV depending on the selection. The HTML code is generated and there can be 1 to 8 selects generated, with each dependent div shown under the its select. I came up with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24604884/3359635).

"Second half" of the code basically finds all `select` elements with given ID, loops trough them and depending on the selected value, shows or hides the div. I had to use this selectors: `$('*[id*=delegate_form]')` and `$('*[id*=show_hidden_delegate')`, because if I used `$("#delegate_form")` the code only affected the element with index 0. I have no idea why.

First half of the code handles the same situation on the read-only page.

Comment: The Show / Hide works fine. What I need is the copy function to work on each div as i want it if the div is click it is copied. The copy function uses a var which is the div's id. So using the function as is I would need to create 19 vars and then right the script out for each var. trying to find a simple way of doing this... I cant use getElementByClass as I am using iE8 which does support the class.

Comment: @user3837156: You do not need `getElementByClass` with jQuery. The class selectors will work with IE8.

Comment: Well you can try to use the selector in the similar way as I did. Something like this http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/ and use it in each loop. Then you can add functionality for every element containing `option`.